# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller not forwarding headers with underscores

Tags: kubernetes, request-headers

I'm having a problem where my kubernetes nginx ingress controller is **NOT** forwarding the headers with underscores in them.

I created a configMap with name `my-release-ingress-nginx-controller` with the following entry.

```
    enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
```

After this i checked the nginx.conf file by describing the nginx ingress controller pod, using this command `kubectl exec -it my-release-ingress-nginx-controller-d7648bcc8-6lfxv cat nginx.conf`. There i found this `underscores_in_headers on;`. Even after this toggle, the nginx is still not forwarding the headers with underscores in it.

ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
data:
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
  ignore-invalid-headers: "false"
```

ConfigMap describe:

```
Name:         my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  
Data
====
enable-underscores-in-headers:
----
true
ignore-invalid-headers:
----
false
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age   From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----  ----                      -------
  Normal  CREATE  27s   nginx-ingress-controller  ConfigMap default/my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
```

Deployment describe

```
Args:
  /nginx-ingress-controller
  --publish-service=default/my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
  --election-id=ingress-controller-leader
  --ingress-class=nginx
  --configmap=default/my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
```

Ingress describe:

```
Name:             ingress-resource-1
Namespace:        default
Address:          172.31.14.220
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                                               Path  Backends
  ----                                               ----  --------
  api.dev.com  
                                                     /   faq-dev:10013 (172.17.0.3:10013)
Annotations:                                         kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
                                                     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                     From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----                    ----                      -------
  Normal  UPDATE  3m10s (x2443 over 20h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/ingress-resource-1
  Normal  UPDATE  2m10s (x2483 over 20h)  nginx-ingress-controller  Ingress default/ingress-resource-1
```

PS: I have setup a single node kubernetes cluster using minikube , inside an AWS ec2 server. Also the ingress is configured as a deployment and not a daemonset.The ingress configured is the kubernetes one from this repository - https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Answer (score 2):

Try this Please

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
  ignore-invalid-headers: "false"
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: default
```

and include the same in nginx-ingress-controller-deployment

```
containers:
  - name: nginx-ingress-controller
    image: <YOUR NGINX INGRSS IMAGE_NAME>
    args:
      - /nginx-ingress-controller
      - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration
    env:
      - name: POD_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.name
      - name: POD_NAMESPACE
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

Comment: You know you can edit your original answer to improve or expand it

Comment: @DashrathMundkar I'm getting this error -  `cannot parse 'enable-underscores-in-headers' as bool: strconv.ParseBool: parsing "on": invalid syntax`

Comment: @PremkumarTejnani try with "true"

Comment: @DashrathMundkar I chaged "on" to "true" , and created  the configMap, but the issue still persists

Comment: @PremkumarTejnani, have you `exec` into the ingress to make sure the `configmap` is being added properly?

Comment: @Crou yes , i run this command  `kubectl exec -it my-release-ingress-nginx-controller-d7648bcc8-6lfxv cat nginx.conf`  and found  `underscores_in_headers on` , this means that the value for **underscore_in_headers** is changing to **on** but still the nginx server is not forwarding the headers.

Answer (score 1):

create new configmap with the below menifest & delete the pod of nginx controller which basically create new nginx controller with new configmap configuration.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
  ignore-invalid-headers: "false"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-release-ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
```

Comment: no need to create new, just edit existing

Answer (score 0):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: default
```

[enabling underscore in headers](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#enable-underscores-in-headers)

After adding this to the configuration, a rolling restart is required for the config to be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

If someone uses the ingress-nginx helm chart the solution is:
https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/e09e40af1ad33cf748ee92502f61ec2b6f741b96/charts/ingress-nginx/templates/controller-configmap.yaml#L26

Configuring the values:

```
  values: |
    controller:
      config:
          enable-underscores-in-headers: "true"
          ignore-invalid-headers: "false"
          allow-snippet-annotations: "true"
```